# ParseExact and TryParseExact methods are not accepting the multiple dateformats in powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-table-storage, azure-powershell, datetime-parsing

I have different types of date formats like `MM/d/yyyy`, `MM/dd/yyyy` etc.. I want to parse the different formats of string value to datetime in PowerShell.

```
[string[]]$format = @("MM/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt","M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt","MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt","M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")

$dateString = "11/8/2017 02:40:31 PM"

Write-Host ([datetime]::ParseExact($dateString, $format, $null))
```

when I'm executing above lines I'm getting below exception

```
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:5 char:1
+ Write-Host ([datetime]::ParseExact($dateString, $format, $null))
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

I want to parse string value to datetime and the string is can be in any format.
Can anyone tell me how to achieve this using PowerShell.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works, although I didn't find a way to make it work with that specific overload of DateTime.ParseExact().

```
[string[]] $format = @("MM/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt","M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt","MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt","M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
$dateString = "11/8/2017 02:40:31 PM"

$result = $null
$format.ForEach({ [DateTime] $dt = New-Object DateTime; if([datetime]::TryParseExact($dateString, $_, [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None, [ref] $dt)) { $result = $dt } });

Write-Host ($result)
```

Output:

```
11/8/2017 2:40:31 PM
```